# What is the difference between %w and %W

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm looking at the documentation for Ruby. I'm confused between using `%w()` or `%W()` (Later `W` is upcase). What is the difference between both? Can you point me to some documentation?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

When capitalized, the array is constructed from strings that are interpolated, as would happen in a double-quoted string; when lowercased, it is constructed from strings that are not interpolated, as would happen in a single-quoted string. For example:

```
irb(main):001:0> foo = "bar"
=> "bar"
irb(main):002:0> %w(#{foo} bar baz)
=> ["\#{foo}", "bar", "baz"]
irb(main):003:0> %W(#{foo} bar baz)
=> ["bar", "bar", "baz"]
irb(main):004:0> ^D
```

Comment: he means you can do stuff like %W!test te#{variable}st!, the #{variable} will be interprated. in a %w, it will be seen as a simple string.

Comment: @BhushanLodha: Sure. Added one.

Comment: In other words: the difference between `%w` and `%W` is the same as the difference between `%q` and `%Q`.